# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'turn' referenced before assignment - python

Tags: python, processing

tried looking this up but no one had this issue for a global variable. for some reason, it keeps giving me this error if I don't put global turn inside of the function.

```
global turn
turn = 1
def turn_changer():
    if turn == 1:
        turn = 2
    else:
        turn = 1
```

Comment: You are using `turn` across scopes. What you are trying is possible if you declare it `global` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you will use the ‘global’ `turn` variable, this will work:

```py
turn = 1
def turn_changer():
    global turn
    if turn == 1:
        turn = 2
    else:
        turn = 1
```

Comment: sorry, it edited out the part where I had global outside of the function, whenever I call it outside of the function it gives me the error that I'm calling it before it is made, I've updated the code

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#more-about-scope-crossing-boundaries) may be helpful for you. Essentially, you cannot access variables outside of a function because of python's variable scoping. The compiler is expecting a local variable (inside the function body) named `turn`.

When it doesn't find it, it throws the error you describe. So if you need to reference that variable, you can either specify `global turn` as you suggest, or you can pass the variable `turn` into the function.

Comment: sorry, it edited out the part where I had global outside of the function, whenever I call it outside of the function it gives me the error that I'm calling it before it is made, I've updated the code

Comment: In that case @ArcticFox's answer is the better option

Comment: As far as I'm aware, in your code the line `global turn` isn't doing anything. Just creating the variable outside of a method/class implies that is it already global